# In mobile platform, OpenCL 'asynchronous memory transfers' is impossible?

Tags: android, opencl

I tried to apply 'asynchronous memory transfer' which GPU for execution is overlapped with host for data transfer to Adreno GPU. I profiled the app with Adreno profiler. The result is not overlapped between GPU execution and data transfer. 
My Question is 'asynchronous memory transfer' can be applied to mobile platform?

Comment: (I am assuming your implementation is correct). This depends on the number of asynchronous engines available on the device. I am not sure how to query this information from the OpenCL API itself. Perhaps refer to the Adreno documentation?

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva With Adreno profiler tool that Qualcomm provide, I checked it.

Comment: How many command queues did you use?